# Are there real life cases when C4930 Visual C++ warning doesn't indicate an error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, warnings, compiler-warnings

Visual C++ can emit [C4930 "unused function prototype" warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ddd21xh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in the following case:

```
void SomeUsefulFunction()
{
    SomeResourceLock lock(); //C4930 - unused function prototype
    //code requiring the above lock
}
```

in the above code the intention was to construct a stack-allocated RAII object:

```
void SomeUsefulFunction()
{
    SomeResourceLock lock; //okay
    //code requiring the above lock
}
```

but since the parentheses were typed variable definition turned into a function prototype and so no RAII object is constructed and there's no "lock" object and code behavior is changed.

Also the warning is only triggered when an unused prototype is inside a function, not at class level. It seems pretty useless to have a function prototype inside a function *and* not call the prototyped function.

Now I'm tempted to use `pragma warning` to make Visual C++ treat that particular warning as error.

Are there any real life cases when C4930 doesn't accompany an error?

Comment: It seems to me that C4930 is designed to specifically catch this type of error. Besides, I typically use `/W4` and `/WX` together to catch the most errors at compile-time, rather than runtime.

Comment: @In silico: IMO that's good practice, but many developers find /WX annoying since it sometimes breaks nightly builds for no serious reasons.

Comment: I think you mean are there cases where somebody would *need* to do this. Since technically it is never an error. I would say, no, nobody should ever need to have an unused function prototype. They may however exist in some macro and template code, depending on how the optimization is done.

Comment: The fact that it is unused and whether it is an error are different issues. As with any other unused thing (think unused variable), having no purpose means that noone should ever need it there, but that does not mean that it is an error to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ makes it legal to make function-local declarations, although I've rarely seen this feature used. It's often an error, but for instance, if you *really* used such a declaration and called the matching function:

```
int main()
{
    int foo();
    return foo();
}
```

And then later removed the function call:

```
int main()
{
    int foo();
    return 0;
}
```

It would be stupid if suddenly it didn't compile anymore.

So, real-world cases where this does not indicate an error on your end are next to nonexistant, but compilers have to account for imaginary-world issues too, because sometimes the real world gets pretty unreal. Showing a warning seems like a good tradeoff for me: the compiler tells you it's unsure if it's what you really wanted.

Point is, compiler writers can't make it an error, because it's syntactically valid. If you want to treat it as an error in your code, it probably won't cause you any problem.

Answer (score 2):

From your very own link,

> C4930 can also occur when the compiler cannot distinguish between a function prototype declaration and a function call.

Of course that alone is probably not sufficient reason to not treat that warning as an error. If the compiler is confused, somebody reading the code might be too, and it should probably be made less ambiguous anyway.

Comment: I actually don't get how the latter problem could occur in well-written code. Do you know any such case?

Comment: @sharptooth: The example they show is plausible, and it *is* a bit easy to make something look like a function prototype. That said, I think it's fine to treat this warning as an error.

Comment: @sharptooth: Maybe it's lack of experience? It's a common case of trap to avoid in C++.

Comment: @Klaim: Which trap exactly do you mean?

Comment: Class object(); // object is a function here, not an object... that's C++.

Comment: @Klaim: Well, yes, but if it's `Class object( whatever );` it's an object, and so it's not always that trivial to see.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a trap : there is only one case where the same kind of writing is not an object construction. It LOOKS like an object construction, in the context, but it is not. Like a trap. If you have a parameter, then it's easy to avoid, without even knowing about this C++ rule.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I compile with "treat warnings as errors", **all** warnings, and I think that is a sane decision. While the first time that you enable this feature you will spend some time fixing all warnings before the build is clean, from there on the extra cost of cleaning any introduced warning tends to be small, and they do catch some errors.

As to whether a warning can not be an error in any case, of course. For that particular warning, imagine that you declared a function in the namespace and used it, and later in some refactoring your code no longer needs the function. If you remove the call, the compiler will trigger that warning, and in that particular case nothing is broken. Still, as I already said, I would remove the declaration to have a warning-free build.

Comment: The warning is only triggered when the prototype is inside a function.

Comment: @sharptooth: how does that affect the answer? `int main() { void foo(); foo(); } void foo() { std::cout << "Hi"; }` is a valid construct, then you can remove the call to `foo()` inside main, and you will get the warning. That warning is not so different from any unused variable, it just happens to be more unusual to declare a function inside another function.

Answer (score 0):

```
void UnusedFunctionPrototype();
```

Comment: That doesn't trigger that warning unless it is done inside a function.